# What’s wrong in my code with for loop and array_rand()?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, random

I need to output a random string with 10 alphanumeric/underscore characters, the first of which must NOT be a number. My code is as follows:

```
$arr = array_merge(range("a", "z"), range("A", "Z"), array("_"));
$name = array_rand($arr);
$arr = array_merge($arr, range(0, 9));
    for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++)
    {
    $name .= array_rand($arr);
    }
echo $name;
```

But the output is, quite strangely, always something like `3329323960047113937` or `933255318725381013` or `48212116303047152448`. Why is it more than ten characters and why does it begin with a number (though when I initiated the variable `$name` there were no numbers inside `$arr`)? Should I use `foreach` instead of `for` loop? Or should I use some other function than `array_rand()`? I’m only a beginner in PHP, so sorry for the stupid question. And thanks in advance to everybody.

Comment: `foreach` and `for` loop won't make difference on output. They are just different looping flow. Also, `array_ran()` returns array key, not value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

array_rand returns a random array key, not a random array entry. More info can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

I've corrected your code:

```
$arr = array_merge(range("a", "z"), range("A", "Z"), array("_"));
$name = $arr[array_rand($arr)];
$arr = array_merge($arr, range(0, 9));
    for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++)
    {
    $name .= $arr[array_rand($arr)];
    }
echo $name;
```

Output example:

```
NQvCKSkyym
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.. The `array_rand()` returns you just the random key from your array. You need to subject it inside the array to get the random element.

```
<?php
$arr = array_merge(range("a", "z"), range("A", "Z"), array("_"));
$arr = array_merge($arr, range(0, 9));
    for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++)
    {
    //$name .= array_rand($arr);
    $key = array_rand($arr);
    $name .=$arr[$key];
    }
echo $name;
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
5Ts9hz7NZ5
```

Comment: I’ve tested your code... The output always begins with a number and is often more than ten characters.

Comment: Replace `echo $name;` with `echo substr(strrev($name),1);`

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue. The problem is the array_rand on line 2 is returning an array key, not an array entry, that needs to be corrected.